# Lecture Notes in Computer Science (LNCS) - Springer, can't see \authorrunning and \titlerunning

Tags: lncs

I almost finished TeXing out my Springer's article but have problems with `\authorrunning` and `\titlerunning` using `llncs`. I downloaded this: ftp://ftp.springernature.com/cs-proceeding/llncs/llncs2e.zip and followed the example to create my own article. But, don't know why, I can't see authors and title at the top of every page of my article. Here's a MWE, I just cut my article content, still - it "does not work". Take a look:

```
\documentclass{llncs}

\usepackage{makeidx}                    
\usepackage{floatrow}                   
\usepackage{fancyhdr}                   

\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=bottom}
\newcommand{\keywords}[1]{\par\addvspace\baselineskip
\noindent\keywordname\enspace\ignorespaces#1}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\makeatletter
\let\runauthor\@author
\let\runtitle\@title
\makeatother
\lhead{\runauthor}
\rhead{\runtitle}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter                                    
\pagestyle{headings}                    

\mainmatter                                 

\title{my title}
\titlerunning{my title}

\author{author1 name\inst{1} and  author2 name\inst{1,2}}
\authorrunning{author1 name}

\institute{University 1 \\
\email{email1@gmail.com}
\and
University 2 \\
\email{email2@gmail.com}
}

\maketitle            

\begin{abstract}
....
\end{abstract}

\section{Introduction}
...
\newpage

\section{Introduction}
...
\newpage

\section{Introduction}
...
\newpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems that I solved my own question: it worked when I changed `\documentclass{llncs}` to `\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}` .. but would be very grateful to see other answers, because in the zip file from Springers FTP they do not use `\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}` and it's working ... magic?

Comment: Of course `\pagestyle{headings}` will nullify `\pagestyle{fancy}`. Don't use `fancyhdr` with `llncs`, just use the features the class provides.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks, good point! :) Final version: http://pastie.org/private/ydxn3lucvvfhzyh7lwpkw. But it still "does not work" when I use `\documentclass{llncs}` instead of `\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}`

Comment: Why shouldn't you use the `runningheads` option?